# Android: Lock/Freeze layout for the time changes are made programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I do reorganization of my layout programmatically adding and removing several views. The problem is after the first `removeView` the activity/fragment starts to measure/layout the remaining views. Is it possible to put this on hold until I have done all the changes?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the post from Arkde I finally found a solution for my problem. I simply override `requestLayout()` and prevent the call to be propagated to the parent `ViewGroup` on demand. This enable me to stop the layout process from interfering as long as I reorganize my views.

Comment: Ubfortunately `View.measure` does not work without requestLayout.

Answer (score 0):

**1st idea**

Removes a range of views during layout.The `removeView()` method looks like this in `ViewGroup`

```
public void removeView(View view) {
    removeViewInternal(view);
    requestLayout();
    invalidate(true);
}
```

The calls to `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` cause your group to trigger measure/layout methods.

In order to avoid this mechanism, you should extend your `ViewGroup` and override this method, or create a new one to remove chunks of views,and after that trigger `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()`

or, if you want to remove all the views starting at a certain position, to another position in layout use,

```
public void removeViews(int start, int count) {
    removeViewsInternal(start, count);
    requestLayout();
    invalidate(true);
}
```

that removes a range of views during layout.

**2nd idea**

If you want your layout to be dynamic and you want to grammatically add or remove parts of the screen, I think you should use `Fragments` instead.

**3rd idea**

When you need to change your layout, just create another `ViewGroup` programatically (or by inflating from xml different layouts), and add all the childs you need there. After that remove all views from current view using `ViewGroup.removeAllViews()`and add the newly created `ViewGroup`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is removeViewInternal() is private so override removeView() will create another problem.

Comment: You can access those methods using reflection. If that doesn't fit your needs, then maybe you should remove some views using `removeViews(int start, int count) and add back the views you need.  If even these methods do not fit your needs, I advice you to use fragments and manipulate those fragments instead of views